# Use 7zip to create archives for each subfolder and file

Tags: windows, command-line, 7-zip, archiving

Under Windows environment, I have a folder contains both subfolders and isolated files. The structure is like this:

D:\main_folder

- subfolder1
- subfolder2
- file1.dat

I want to use 7zip to make the following archives automatically:

E:\main_folder\subfolder1.7z

E:\main_folder\subfolder2.7z

E:\main_folder\file1.7z

The problem I have is, if I use `for /d %i in (*) do 7z`, it excludes the isolated files, while if I use `for %i in (*.*) do 7z` or `for %i in (*) do 7z`, it excludes the subfolders.

Comment: Why are you going for outdated batch as the 1st idea to solve this? It's 2 minutes of work in PowerShell, if you know the basics. This is also almost definitely a duplicate, if we ignore the irrelevant 7z part.